# Counting the number of occurrences of smileys in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am creating a method that counts all occurrences of **smileys** in a string.
(I have already created another method that queries a database to get the smiley strings.)

I would like this method to be able to detect `:-):-)` as two occurrences. Here is what I have tried:

```
public static int Occurrences(string input)
{
    int count = 0;

    Smileys list = SmileyDAL.GetAll();

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        count += new Regex(item.Key).Matches(input).Count;

    }

    return count;
}
```

But I'm getting this error when calling this method:

> parsing ";-)" - Too many )'s.

Comment: How is your input looking like? :-)? try :-\\)

Comment: Please add your regular expression

Comment: Are there different smileys or just the one `:-)`? E.G is `;) a smiley?

Answer (score 4):

You 'll need to escape the `)` character, replace:

```
count += new Regex(item.Key).Matches(input).Count;
```

with:

```
count += new Regex(Regex.Escape(item.Key)).Matches(input).Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Regex(Regex.Escape(item.Key))
```

You have to escape the regular expression characters in your search string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option not using regex

```
public static int Occurences(string input)
{
    // Put all smileys into an array.
    var smileys = SmileyDAL.GetAll().Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();

    // Split the string on each smiley.
    var split = input.Split(smileys, StringSplitOptions.None);

    // The number of occurences equals the length less 1.
    return split.Length - 1;
}
```